# Child process receives parent's SIGINT

Tags: c++, c, linux, unix

I have one simple program that's using Qt Framework. 
It uses QProcess to execute RAR and compress some files. In my program I am catching `SIGINT` and doing something in my code when it occurs:

```
signal(SIGINT, &unix_handler);
```

When `SIGINT` occurs, I check if RAR process is done, and if it isn't I will wait for it ... The problem is that (I think) RAR process also gets `SIGINT` that was meant for my program and it quits before it has compressed all files.

Is there a way to run RAR process so that it doesn't receive `SIGINT` when my program receives it?

Thanks

Comment: Currently I'm testing it on Debian 5.0.8

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you are generating the `SIGINT` with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> on a Unix system, then the signal is being sent to the entire [process group](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap11.html#tag_11_01_02).

You need to use [setpgid](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setpgid.html) or [setsid](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setsid.html) to put the child process into a different process group so that it will not receive the signals generated by the controlling terminal.

---

[Edit:]

Be sure to read the RATIONALE section of the `setpgid` page carefully.  It is a little tricky to plug all of the potential race conditions here.

To guarantee 100% that no `SIGINT` will be delivered to your child process, you need to do something like this:

```
#define CHECK(x) if(!(x)) { perror(#x " failed"); abort(); /* or whatever */ }
/* Block SIGINT. */
sigset_t mask, omask;
sigemptyset(&mask);
sigaddset(&mask, SIGINT);
CHECK(sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &mask, &omask) == 0);

/* Spawn child. */
pid_t child_pid = fork();
CHECK(child_pid >= 0);
if (child_pid == 0) {
    /* Child */
    CHECK(setpgid(0, 0) == 0);
    execl(...);
    abort();
}
/* Parent */
if (setpgid(child_pid, child_pid) < 0 && errno != EACCES)
    abort(); /* or whatever */
/* Unblock SIGINT */
CHECK(sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &omask, NULL) == 0);
```

Strictly speaking, every one of these steps is necessary.  You have to block the signal in case the user hits <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> right after the call to `fork`.  You have to call `setpgid` in the child in case the `execl` happens before the parent has time to do anything.  You have to call `setpgid` in the parent in case the *parent* runs and someone hits <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> before the *child* has time to do anything.

The sequence above is clumsy, but it does handle 100% of the race conditions.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think that's answer to my problem. I'll try it ASAP ;)

Comment: It's working, I just added correct include and this line: setpgid(rar.pid(), 0);

Comment: No problem.  Note that `setpgid` is fraught with race conditions, and using it correctly is a bit delicate.  I have updated my answer to be more complete.

Comment: Thank you for additional info ;)

Comment: typo in last if. EACCES and not EACCESS

Comment: This use of `assert` is extremely wrong! `assert` is conditionally enabled or disabled and when disabled, it eliminates it's argument altogether. You should be using `if(1!...) abort()` or your own macro wrapping it.

Comment: @Jan - The `/* or whatever */` was meant to imply "whatever your error-handling policy is".  Whether this use of `assert` is "wrong" depends entirely on that policy.  (Where I work, we never compile with `NDEBUG`, so `assert` is usable for "this should never happen" cases.)

Comment: @Nemo: The "/* or whatever */" was right. But the important calls wrapped in `assert` were not. It so happens that in Linux you usually don't have control over whether the code will be compiled with `NDEBUG` or not as it's rather easy to call `configure CPPFLAGS="-O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -DNDEBUG"`

Comment: @Jan - I disagree with your edit, so I reverted it.  Your comments are still here for anybody who stumbles across this in the future.

Comment: @Jan: Using `assert` for "impossible" cases is perfectly normal and perfectly correct.  (And you will note this code only uses `assert` for such impossible cases; the `fork` that could actually fail is checked explicitly.)  Your downvote is based on your personal opinion, not technical fact nor standard practice.  I added `/* or whatever */` to the `assert` cases to make you happy, even though it is not strictly necessary.  Fair enough?

Comment: @Nemo: Yes, but provided that: 1) the expression in argument of `assert` has no side effects (violated here) and 2) the condition may only be true if there is a bug in the program (that's not the case of `setpgid` result).

Comment: @Jan: Well, I disagree about `assert` being appropriate for expressions that are "only true if there is a bug in your program".  In this context, `setpgid(0,0)` can fail only if there is a bug in the C library or the kernel, and checking such "impossible" cases with `assert` is perfectly reasonable. But you have a good point about side-effects. I thought `assert(x)` was guaranteed to evaluate `x`, but I was wrong.  I have reverted to your version.

Comment: Won't this be problematic if the child is somehow prioritized over the parent and hangs because the unblocking of the signals is only done in the parent?

Comment: @Sarien: Regardless of priorities, both processes are guaranteed to make progress "eventually". Hitting Ctrl-C while the signal is blocked will cause it to be queued and delivered once it is "eventually" unblocked.

Comment: @Nemo Okay, but still it might run for a long time without being able to receive signals, right?

Answer (score 0):

What are you doing in your handler? There are only certain Qt functions that you can call safely from a unix signal handler. [This page](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/unix-signals.html) in the documentation identifies what ones they are.

The main problem is that the handler will execute outside of the main Qt event thread. That page also proposes a method to deal with this. I prefer getting the handler to "post" a custom event to the application and handle it that way. I posted an answer describing how to implement custom events [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/unix-signals.html).

Comment: Thank you for this page, I wasn't aware of it. I'm just calling quit and wait on my threads, and then exiting the application. It works for everything except RAR, so I don't think it's the problem. But I will read this page. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Just make the subprocess *ignore* SIGINT:

```
child_pid = fork();
if (child_pid == 0) {
   /* child process */
   signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN);
   execl(...);
}
```

`man sigaction`:

> During an execve(2), the dispositions of handled signals are reset to the default;
> the dispositions of ignored signals are left unchanged.