# Killing Subshell with SIGTERM

Tags: shell, kill, sigterm

I'm sure this is really simple, but it's biting me in the face anyway, and I'm a little frustrated and stumped.

So, I have a script which I've managed to boil down to:

```
#!/bin/sh
sleep 50 | echo
```

If I run that at the command line, and hit Ctrl-C it stops, like I would expect.

If I send it sigint, using kill, it does nothing.
I thought that was strange, since I thought those should have been the same.

Then, if I send it sigterm, then it also dies, but if I look in ps, the sleep is still running.

What am I missing, here?

This is obviously not the real script, which runs python, and it's more of a problem when it keeps running after start-stop-daemon tries to kill the daemon.

Help me people. I'm dumb.

Comment: Bash's mechanism probably somehow prevents SIGINT signals not sent by the keyboard to be handled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this happens is that the Ctrl-C is delivered to the sleep process, whereas the sigint you are sending is delivered only to the script itself.  See [Child process receives parent's SIGINT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6803395/child-process-receives-parents-sigint) for details on this.

You can verify this yourself by using `strace -p` when hitting ctrl-c or sending sigint; strace will tell you what signals are delivered.

EDIT: I don't think you are dumb.  Processes and how they work are seemingly simple, but the details are often complicated, and even experts get confused by this sort of thing.

Comment: More specifically, Ctrl-C sends `SIGINT` to the current process *group*, which means the signal is propagated to all processes (the shell and both processes on either end of the pipe) in the group.

Answer (score 0):

I did the same thing I written script named as test.sh with below containt.

```
#!/bin/sh
sleep 50 | echo
```

After executing , I did  `Ctrl-C` -> its working fine means closing it.
Again executed and in another terminal i checked the PID by `ps -ef|grep test.sh` after finding the pid , i did `kill <pid>` and it killed the process , to verify again i executed `ps -ef|grep test.sh` and didnt get any pid.