# Spawn child process with other process group

Tags: node.js, windows, process, spawn, sigint

I am catching `SIGINT` signal to gracefully shutdown app. I am use child process which I would like to keep till I complete shutdown (by default child process have same process group and it recievs signal same time). I use [spawn](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v6.x/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options)  to start child process and try to use it with `gid` option.

```
            var child = spawn(pathToFFMPEG,[
                '-t',  duration,
                '-i', station.streamEndpoint,
                '-f', 'mp3',
                'pipe:1'
            ],{
                gid: Math.ceil(Math.random()*100000)
            })
```

I got `ENOTSUP` error when I try to start child process (without `gid` option process starts normally).

How to correct set up process group for child process using spawn? In my example I generate `gid` randomly but it seems it's not good idea even without above error.
 I read this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6803395/child-process-receives-parents-sigint) before my experiment with `gid` . Thanks.

**Edit**

It seems `gid` is not supported (at least [directly](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_setgroups_groups) setting it). Are there any options to avoid closing child process with `SIGINT` signal?

Comment: How is `SIGINT`a factor here? Windows doesn't implement POSIX signals, so the only `SIGINT` that exists has to be a function of a runtime library. Usually it's the C runtime library, which raises `SIGINT` in response to a console `CTRL_C_EVENT`.

Comment: I don't see a way to explicitly pass the normal process creation flags via node.js `spawn`. I see that specifying `detached` passes the flag to create a new group, but whoever wrote this line -- [`process_flags |= DETACHED_PROCESS | CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v9.x/deps/uv/src/win/process.c#L1073) -- needs to spend more time researching how the console works and how it uses process groups. They documented this option as "[t]he child will have its own console window". No, it won't have any console, and thus creating a new process group is really pointless.